# change position of edge label and caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I have create the following graph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,automata,positioning} 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} % natuerliche Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} % ganze Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} % rationale Zahlen
    \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % reelle Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}} % Symbol fuer Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaß
    \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % Symbol fuer Erwartungswert
    \newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
    \newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
    \newcommand{\vf}{\mathbf{v}}
    \newcommand{\Df}{\mathbf{D}}
    \newcommand{\af}{\pmb{\alpha}}
    \newcommand{\eef}{\mathbf{e}}
    \newcommand{\Psf}{\pmb{\Psi}}
    \newcommand{\Phf}{\pmb{\Phi}}
    \newcommand{\bef}{\pmb{\beta}}
    \newcommand{\Pf}{\mathbf{P}}
    \newcommand{\Qf}{\mathbf{Q}}
    \newcommand{\mf}{\mathbf{m}}
    \newcommand{\ef}{\pmb{\varepsilon}}
    \newcommand{\Hf}{\mathbf{H}}
    \newcommand{\Ef}{\mathbf{E}}
    \newcommand{\Mf}{\mathbf{M}}
    \newcommand{\Vf}{\mathbf{V}}
    \newcommand{\gf}{\mathbf{g}}
    \newcommand{\QSo}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S'}}
    \newcommand{\QSot}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S''}}
    \newcommand{\QSt}{\mathbf{Q}_{S'' S''}}
    \newcommand{\UP}[2]{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\raisebox{1.5em}{$\phantom{#2}#1$}}}#2}
    \newcommand{\LF}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{$#1$\hspace{4.5em}}}
    \newcommand{\zfo}{\mathbf{z}_{1}}
    \newcommand{\zft}{\mathbf{z}_{2}}
    \newcommand{\zf}{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    semithick,
 every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white,circle},
 every loop/.append style={looseness=5}]
  \path[use as bounding box] (-2.7,0.45) rectangle (15,-10.65);
  \node[state]         (A)              {$A_{2}(0)$};
  \node                (B) [right=of A] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right=of B] {$A_{1}(0)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node                (E) [right=of D] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (F) [right=of E] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (G) [below=of D] {$A_{2}$(n{-}2)};
  \node                (H) [right=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (I) [right=of H] {$A_{1}$(n{-}2)};
  \node[state]         (J) [below=of G]  {$A_{2}$(n{-}1)};
  \node                (K) [right=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (L) [right=of K] {$A_{1}$(n{-}1)};



  \path (A) edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (B)
            edge [left]       node {$\QAt$}                         (D)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (F)
        (C) edge [above]      node {$\QAow$}                        (B)
            edge [above]      node {$\QAot$}                        (D)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAo$}                         (F)
        (D) edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (E)
                              node(aux) {}                          (G)
        (F) edge [above]      node {$\QAow$}                        (E)
                              node(aux1) {}                         (I)
        (G) edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (H)
            edge [left]       node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (L)
        (I) edge [above]      node {$\QAow$}                        (H)
            edge              node {$\QAot$}                        (J)
            edge              node {$\QAo$}                         (L)
        (J) edge [above]      node {$1$}                            (K)
        (L) edge [above]      node {$1$}                            (K);
\node[below=8mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\vdots};
\node[below=8mm of aux1,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\vdots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\"Ubergangsgraph von $X$.}\label{Abbildung4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It looks as follows
[image]

The proble is that I want to change the position of the edge label in the middle of the two subgraph and also to achieve that the caption is not in the graph. Thanks for any help

it should look as follows
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pos=...` ?

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Replace the upper part of your code by `\path (A) edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (B)
            edge [left]       node {$\QAt$}                         (D)
            edge              node[pos=0.3] {$\QAto$}               (F)
        (C) edge           node {$\QAow$}                       (B)
            edge           node[pos=0.3] {$\QAot$}       (D)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestion to use `pos` key by @marmot is great, but it won't get you to look exactly how you want.  It takes you about 90% of the way.  Here is what it looks like using only `pos=0.8` (i.e. 80% along the line from the start node to the end node):

[image: Using pos=0.8 in current OP]

You'll notice that the labels are not exactly positioned where you want.  You have two options (or both) to deal with this.  The easiest is to *also* specify the position (e.g. `above`, `east`, `below`, etc.) in addition to `pos=...`.  Here is the complete MWE, plus anchor and `pos` specified for those line labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,automata,positioning} 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} % natuerliche Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} % ganze Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} % rationale Zahlen
    \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % reelle Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}} % Symbol fuer Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaß
    \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % Symbol fuer Erwartungswert
    \newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
    \newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
    \newcommand{\vf}{\mathbf{v}}
    \newcommand{\Df}{\mathbf{D}}
    \newcommand{\af}{\pmb{\alpha}}
    \newcommand{\eef}{\mathbf{e}}
    \newcommand{\Psf}{\pmb{\Psi}}
    \newcommand{\Phf}{\pmb{\Phi}}
    \newcommand{\bef}{\pmb{\beta}}
    \newcommand{\Pf}{\mathbf{P}}
    \newcommand{\Qf}{\mathbf{Q}}
    \newcommand{\mf}{\mathbf{m}}
    \newcommand{\ef}{\pmb{\varepsilon}}
    \newcommand{\Hf}{\mathbf{H}}
    \newcommand{\Ef}{\mathbf{E}}
    \newcommand{\Mf}{\mathbf{M}}
    \newcommand{\Vf}{\mathbf{V}}
    \newcommand{\gf}{\mathbf{g}}
    \newcommand{\QSo}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S'}}
    \newcommand{\QSot}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S''}}
    \newcommand{\QSt}{\mathbf{Q}_{S'' S''}}
    \newcommand{\UP}[2]{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\raisebox{1.5em}{$\phantom{#2}#1$}}}#2}
    \newcommand{\LF}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{$#1$\hspace{4.5em}}}
    \newcommand{\zfo}{\mathbf{z}_{1}}
    \newcommand{\zft}{\mathbf{z}_{2}}
    \newcommand{\zf}{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    semithick,
 every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white,circle},
 every loop/.append style={looseness=5}]
  \path[use as bounding box] (-2.7,0.45) rectangle (15,-10.65);
  \node[state]         (A)              {$A_{2}(0)$};
  \node                (B) [right=of A] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right=of B] {$A_{1}(0)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node                (E) [right=of D] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (F) [right=of E] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (G) [below=of D] {$A_{2}$(n{-}2)};
  \node                (H) [right=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (I) [right=of H] {$A_{1}$(n{-}2)};
  \node[state]         (J) [below=of G]  {$A_{2}$(n{-}1)};
  \node                (K) [right=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (L) [right=of K] {$A_{1}$(n{-}1)};



    \path (A)   edge                        node {$\QAtw$}  (B)
                edge [left]                 node {$\QAt$}       (D)
                edge [pos=0.8]              node {$\QAto$}  (F)
        (C)     edge [above]                node {$\QAow$}  (B)
                edge [above left,pos=0.8]   node {$\QAot$}  (D)
                edge [right]                    node {$\QAo$}       (F)
        (D)     edge                        node {$\QAtw$}  (E)
                                            node(aux) {}        (G)
        (F)     edge [above]                node {$\QAow$}  (E)
                                            node(aux1) {}       (I)
        (G)     edge                        node {$\QAtw$}  (H)
                edge [left]                 node {$\QAt$}       (J)
                edge [pos=0.8]              node {$\QAto$}  (L)
        (I)     edge [above]                node {$\QAow$}  (H)
                edge [above left,pos=0.8]   node {$\QAot$}  (J)
                edge                        node {$\QAo$}       (L)
        (J)     edge [above]                node {$1$}          (K)
        (L)     edge [above]                node {$1$}          (K);

\node[below=8mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\vdots};
\node[below=8mm of aux1,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\vdots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\"Ubergangsgraph von $X$.}\label{Abbildung4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Add anchor and pos to the line label options]

It looks to me this covers your need... however, if you want *more* flexibility, consider also using `xshift` or `yshift` for the node label.  Here, I will `xshift` the bottom left **Q**<sub>*A*<sub>1</sub>*A*<sub>2</sub></sub> label using `xshift=25` (using 25 only to clearly show the change).  Recall, positive `xshift` moves right and negative moves left; positive `yshift` moves up and negative moves down.

In this example, I change only:

```
%edge [above left,pos=0.8]  node {$\QAot$}  (J)% without xshift (current version)
%%%%to
edge [above left,pos=0.8]   node[xshift=25] {$\QAot$}   (J)
```

[image: Adding xshift into the node label options]

Hope these options give you flexibility you need!

Comment: My very compliments for your long and nice answer.